# django login form without django authentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

how to create a login form without using django inbuilt authentication.
i have a table for username and password and i want to retrive data from that table and check it with user provided data.
**Views.py**

`from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import studentDetails
from .forms import loginForm`

`def login(request):`

```
form = loginForm(request.POST or None);
if form.is_valid():
    name = request.POST['name']
    password = request.POST['password']
    query_set = studentDetails.objects.get(name=name)
    if password!=query_set.password:
        context.update({'alert': "wrong password"})


context = {
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

`def dashbord(request):
    return(request, "dashbord.html",{})`

Comment: Any idea for why not use django  inbuild authentication? you can use like user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret') to authenticate, from django document, you have to use authenticate before you login

Comment: well i am creating a portal for my college and i want to retrieve username and password from students table. then authenticate.

Comment: help me guys ASAP!!

Comment: What is the error message you got?

Comment: i unable to create login form.